# create calculation that looks for same organization and previous year (where to start?)

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

I'm trying to create a form to enter annual reports into a database. Figured out the basic stuff with calculations within year. But now I need to make a calculation to measure annual growth compared to previous years.

There are ~40 different organizations that I am inputting annual reports for into this database. I am using a single table (good idea?) to put all the information into this database. In order to reference the previous year of the same organization I need to match the organization name, and the previous year.

So what I need to do is something like:

If CompanyName matches current record CompanyName, AND ReportYear is -1 of current record ReportYear, 
Then current record Assets minus found record's Assets.

As you can tell I don't have much coding experience for this. However I'm interested in learning. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction for how I would be able to successfully create that statement in MS Access? I think I have to use an iif statement but I don't think there is a Find function and I'm just generally not sure what the proper language is.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concept is correct you just need that translated into SQL. You'll need to turn the columns names and table names into your own but this is what you describe as SQL

```
Select thisYear.CompanyName
  , thisYear.Asset - LastYear.Asset
  , nz(lastYear.asset,'No Prior Year') as [Message]
From CompanyTable as thisYear
Left Join on CompanyTable as lastYear on thisYear.CompanyName = LastYear.CompanyName
and thisYear.ReportYear -1 = lastYear.ReportYear
```

Comment: Thank you! I will build off this and get back!

Comment: Finally able to look at this again. Brad, 3 questions, 1 of which I'm embarrassed to ask.
1. Can one edit a calculated variable in a table to include SQL? (embarrassing because I'm pretty sure the answer is no)
2. Should I be making my form dependent on the Query, and then the query updates the table? So like a form that is based off an action query?
3. The SQL you created (thanks again for your help) is referencing two tables, CompanyTable and thisYear -- however I was hoping to keep everything in one table. So I should create two tables then?

Comment: 1. I'm not sure exactly what you mean but I'm pretty sure you can only use the function available to the Expression Builder to make calculated columns. If you need more complexity make it in a query. In fact, you should usually do it in a query anyway.

Comment: 2. I think your form's record source should be your table. you can have a control (a combobox probably) with the rowsource set to your query. alternatively you can make a subform that is linked to your parent form which does the look up of the previous year's data. since you are not updating the previous year you do not need to make the form's record source the query.

Comment: 3. @Esprit, It is actually referencing one table twice. The first reference I have aliases as `thisYear` and the second reference I have aliased as `lastYear`. The aliases allow us (and are necessary to) join a table to itself as though it is two tables (but it is one table).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about the aliases. What I didn't know you could do was A) make temporary aliases in SQL (neat feature), and B) that the form could reference both queries and the table in the same form.

I'm having trouble updating the output from the query in the form however, it is outputting in the Form View as '#Error'. But I can probably look for further solutions to this on open stack (unless you have a simple answer?) My most sincere appreciation for your help Brad!

Comment: NP. You should probably post another question with the details of how your form is set up if you want to pursue this more.

Comment: Update; Access deleted a line of code, fixed that, now I have the form outputting '#Name?' - Progress!